# Creating Dynamic Validation using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what I am planning to do:

Initial Markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
<span class="control-label"><b>Doc. Number:</b></span>
<input name="documentNumber" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="document.number" smrh-required />
</div>
```

Attempted Markup with my directive:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" ng-class="{'has-error': t01Form.documentNumber.$invalid && t01Form.documentNumber.$dirty}">
<span class="control-label"><b>Doc. Number:</b></span>
<input name="documentNumber" class="form-control " type="text" ng-model="document.number" smrh-required="" required="" />
<p ng-show="t01Form.documentNumber.$invalid && t01Form.documentNumber.$dirty" class="help-block">Document Number is required.</p>
</div>
```

Below is the custom directive I have created to attempt this:

```
app.directive('smrhRequired', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        element.attr('ng-required', "");
        //This way it will only show the red outline if the error happens.
        var errorClass = " {'has-error': " + scope.formName + "." + element[0].name + ".$valid && " + scope.formName + "." + element[0].name + ".$dirty }";
        var currentNgClass = element.parent().attr('ng-class');
        if (currentNgClass != null) {
            element.parent().attr('ng-class', currentNgClass + errorClass);
        } else {
            element.parent().attr('ng-class', errorClass);
        }
        //Adding the error message below the input
        var template = '<p ng-show="' + scope.formName + '.' + element[0].name + '.$invalid && ' + scope.formName + '.' + element[0].name + '.$dirty" class="help-block">' + ' is required.' + '</p>';
        element.parent().append(template);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    },
};
```

});

Now the above functions adds the new markup correctly, but none of the new markup works. 
Even though I added the required attribute dynamically.. the control still show $valid.

The new

I added shows up regardless of the ng-show logic.

I am guessing it is because I am adding elements to DOM after angular has already compiled, but I thought that's what $compile is for?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things:

- ng-class/ng-required are Angular directives. It has to be an
  attribute to the element you want to use it with.
- You need to use    Angular templates with the $compile service as
  described [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/service/%24compile),    before appending your markup to the DOM

Comment: Are you saying that ng-class and ng-required has to be present before I dynamically add them? 
I was thinking that I would be able to add these attributes on the fly. 

Due to the fact my ng-show and ng-class attributes (which I add dynamically) need scope values and the element name, I can't figure out a clean way to use the template. That's why I am trying to do everything dynamically.

Comment: Ng-class and ng-required are not DOM attributes, they are Angular directives. This is why they have to be there on page load.